# Creating an X axis by Month in Recharts

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, charts, recharts

I've been trying to find documentation of how to create custom X axis ticks for a Rechart graph in React. The data I receive comes in the form of

```js
[
  {
    "date": "2020-11-16",
    "gift_cards_purchased": 92.0,
    "gift_cards_redeemed": -1.0,
    "total_payout_amount": 31.16
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-11-23",
    "gift_cards_purchased": 92.0,
    "gift_cards_redeemed": -1.0,
    "total_payout_amount": 31.16
  }
]
```

The problem I'm having is creating a chart that plots this information with every month on the x axis by default.

What I've tried:

```js
<XAxis
  dataKey="name"
  ticks={
    ['Jan','Feb','Mar','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
  }
/>
```

Comment: You can customize your x axis ticks by using formatter attribute , here is a link for a similar question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64692408/how-to-change-the-label-in-recharts/64693113#64693113
in your case you have to format date to month

Comment: @TahaLAGHZALI , I've seen this post but I don't understand how it works. What I'm currently doing is this: 
                        <XAxis dataKey="name" ticks={['Jan','Feb','Mar','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December' ]}/>